# Neo4j visualization with py2neo: TypeError: 'LabelSetView' object is not callable

Tags: neo4j, jupyter-notebook, py2neo

I am trying to follow the example in

https://nicolewhite.github.io/neo4j-jupyter/hello-world.html

```
from scripts.vis import draw
import neo4jupyter

options = {"Person": "name", "Drink": "name", "Manufacturer": "name"}
draw(graph, options)
```

For this part of the code, I encounter this error:

```
ypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-6a87e5426fa3> in <module>
      3 
      4 options = {"Person": "name", "Drink": "name", "Manufacturer": "name"}
----> 5 draw(graph, options)

~\PycharmProjects\Knowledge_Graph\scripts\vis.py in draw(graph, options, physics, limit)
    104         target_id = row[4]
    105 
--> 106         source_info = get_vis_info(source_node, source_id)
    107 
    108         if source_info not in nodes:

~\PycharmProjects\Knowledge_Graph\scripts\vis.py in get_vis_info(node, id)
     91 
     92     def get_vis_info(node, id):
---> 93         node_label = list(node.labels())[0]
     94         prop_key = options.get(node_label)
     95         vis_label = node.properties.get(prop_key, "")

TypeError: 'LabelSetView' object is not callable
```

I read online that there might be some issues with scripts.vis but I am not too sure how to resolve it

Comment: Is there any update on this issue? Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: sorry, did not manage to find a solution

Answer (score 0):

Please checkout the latest version from the below link and it fixes the problem

https://github.com/merqurio/neo4jupyter/issues/5